# What is matter between the OutPost Firewall and Connectify Hotspot?

Tags: windows-7

If I start OutPost Firewall, and then start Connectify Hotspot, my phone cannot get IP address from Connectify-me, if I stop OutPost Firewall, the phone can get IP address, why?
I use Windows 7 home edition.

Comment: Probably the firewall is blocking it. See the firewall settings

Comment: @PratyushNalam The firewall has many setting items, which one can block the connectify, i do not close the firewall which protects my system.

Comment: I didn't tell you to close the firewall. I'm just saying allow connectify access in the firewall